# Python: Order of arguments in a defined function

Tags: python, function

When I evaluate the following function

```
def f(k,varvz,D,z):
    return np.exp(-(k*(np.sqrt(z**2 + D**2)-D)+(0.041-0.0094*k)*z**2)/varvz)


def g(k,varvz,D):
    return integrate.quad(f,-np.inf,np.inf,args=(k,varvz,D))  

a,err= g(1.24,9.61,1.8)    
print a
```

I get `inf`and the following error message

```
inf

c:\users\user1\appdata\local\temp\tmp5iuiuo.py:11: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  return np.exp(-(k*(np.sqrt(z**2 + D**2)-D)+(0.041-0.0094*k)*z**2)/varvz)
```

But if I change the order of arguments in the definition of `f`

```
def f(z,k,varvz,D):
    return np.exp(-(k*(np.sqrt(z**2 + D**2)-D)+(0.041-0.0094*k)*z**2)/varvz)


def g(k,varvz,D):
    return integrate.quad(f,-np.inf,np.inf,args=(k,varvz,D))  

a,err= g(1.24,9.61,1.8)    
print a
```

I get the desired result `14.5716742277`

Why is this so?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you also change `args=(k,varvz,D)`?

Comment: I want to integrate wrt z. k,D,varvz are parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function to integrate (`f`) needs to be passed the axis to integrate along as the *first* argument. This is only true of your second definition. See [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html#scipy.integrate.quad):

> func : function
>
> ```
> A Python function or method to integrate. If func takes many
> arguments, it is integrated along the axis corresponding to the first
> argument.
> ```